# Вывод первого нечетного и четного числа из базы данных SQL

Tags: sql

Есть база данных содержащая ID:

[image: database SQL]

Нужно с этих айдишников вывести:

- Последнее нечетное число и последнее четное число.

**Как такой запрос сделать?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 2 Id
FROM YouTable
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id % 2 ORDER BY Id DESC)
```